# Spacing between section, subsection, subsub... etc

Tags: spacing, sectioning, line-spacing

I'm in the process of writing my bachelor thesis. The problem is: standards.

Question: How to make the spacing between text and titles (chapters, sections, subsections etc.) but still hold the spacing between sequential section+subsection+subsubsection (for example onehalfspacing) (reduce spacing to onehalfspacing between section{1.4} and subsection{1.4.1})

Example 1:

```
\chapter{Практична частина}
...some text...
\section{Обгрунтування}
...other text
```

[image]

It's good enough. 
But in next example:

[image]

there is big gap between section and subsection.

Comment: Especially as we are talking about a thesis here: At the beginning of a section put a) a summary of the following b) explain how this section fits into your methodology and c) how it contributes to your overall approach. There never is an empty gap between two headlines in a submission ready essay.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But the question is still open. 
It's still remains big gaps between pairs (subsubsec-paragraph) other tuples (subsection-subsubsec-paragraph).

Comment: My suggestion would be to insert `\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}` (or something similar) before the `\subsection`. Automating this is fairly difficult as you need to keep the display of these things together and keep track of which ones are empty/not. The latter is difficult since there's no relationship between a sectional unit and its contents really.

Comment: It all depends on the style you use, but you can always change `\parskip`, maybe even use [the parskip package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip?lang=en)

Comment: The `titlesec` package may be of help: it allows you to change easily the spacing of section titles and has an option concernin consecutive titles `aftersep` as opposed to `largest sep`.

Answer (score 7):

Like Bernard said in the comment, to get your sections and texts get stuck to each other without unnecessary whitespaces, you need to add something like this:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}         % you need this package
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} % this reduces space between (sub)sections to 0pt, for example
\AtBeginDocument{%                     % this will reduce spaces between parts (above and below) of texts within a (sub)section to 0pt, for example - like between an 'eqnarray' and text
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}
```

Change values according to your needs.